# Failed install bluepy

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install bluepy on Ubontu 18.04 in venv, but something went wrong and I can't figure out what. Here is the output. How fix it?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/kris/PycharmProjects/testProj/venv/bin/python -u -c 
    'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
    sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6tx3k3a2/bluepy_e86c89a21017447db6c3b0b710501382/setup.py'"'"'; 
    __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6tx3k3a2/bluepy_e86c89a21017447db6c3b0b710501382/setup.py'"'"';
    f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');
    code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
    f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
    
   install --record /tmp/pip-record-bxe7qhpt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/kris/PycharmProjects/testProj/venv/include/site/python3.6/bluepy Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try `pip install -U setuptools wheel`

Comment: Try  `$ sudo apt-get install python-pip libglib2.0-dev
$ sudo pip install bluepy`